# play video from a point defined by the users

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

If i broadcast a video and divide it into packets, and when a users connect to the netgroup and receive the object from the group( the user will receive from specific time let say actual video is 10 minutes and user connect to the group, and seek video for last 5 minutes). how can i achieve this task. is it possible ? i am using flash player 10.1

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but to jump to any point in a video stream you're going to need a server, most likely Flash Media Server or Red5.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but it is a little complicated.

Flash video over HTTP uses progressive display and download.  Random access into the stream is not technically possible.  It may work in some instances when the file is already in the browser's cache, but it is not truly reliable.  If you are stuck with HTTP only, then the only real option is to edit your video into chunks that represent your random access points.  For example, if you have a one hour video, you can make twelve videos representing five minute offsets that play to the end (ie, a 60 min file, a 55 min file, etc).  There are also some techniques to use a custom server and player which inject metadata to allow random access (I know colleagues who have done this, but have never had to do it myself).

Flash video can also play over a [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) connection.  [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) provides this, as do one or two alternates. RTMP / FMS give you lots more options for streaming your video and allows for true random access into the stream.  You can either purchase and host FMS yourself, or go with a hosted solution like [Influxis](http://www.influxis.com/).  Some cloud based solutions are also starting to become available.